# ajax not working for multiple select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have multiple select box by click to add button and all select box have ajax call on change event, but it is not working. Only work s for first.
code is given below.

Following code call ajax for default select box, but not working for next dynamically inserted select box..

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".one").change(function () {
            var one = $('.one').val();
            var company = $('.one').next();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://champbaba.tk/demo/two.php',
                data: {'one': one},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    $(company).html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {
        var companyhtml = $(".one").html();
        $(".add").click(function (e) { //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            $('<select class="one">' + companyhtml + '</select><select class="two"></select>').insertAfter($('.wrap'));
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <select class="one">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <select class="two">

    </select>
</div>
<button class="add">Add</button>
```

Comment: I have still no idea what your script should do. Can you explain it a little bit better?

Comment: Hey, @Champ IDK what do you want to do ... please explain clearly

Comment: there are two select box namely one and two where two is based on one's selection. and these both select box are multiple (means they are added any times by clicking on 'add' button). and all two selections are based on one selection box. @NeerajPathak

Answer (score 2):

It's working but I thought it's not a good way to work like that you need to search about that how to reinitialize event.

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
        var companyhtml = $(".one").html();
        $(".add").click(function (e) { //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            $('<select class="one">' + companyhtml + '</select><select class="two"></select> <br>').insertAfter($('.wrap'));
            
             $("select").change(function () {
                var one = $(this).html();
                var company = $(this).next('select').html(one)
                $(this).next('select').val(1);
           });
        });
        
          $("select").change(function () {
              var one = $(this).html();
              var company = $(this).next('select').html(one)
              $(this).next('select').val(1);
           });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <select class="one">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <select class="two">

    </select>
</div>
<button class="add">Add</button>
```

try it now.

Comment: Yes, It works. any optimized method to do this? Thanks.  @Neeraj Pathak

Comment: But it does not have ajax value... and Also added ajax code inside it. but same problem with @Obsidian Age answer...

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is one of **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**.

You're attempting to affix an event handler to an element that doesn't actually exist in the DOM at the time the handler is attached. Adding `$(document).ready()` won't resolve this, because the element is generated **dynamically**, after page load.

To work around this, you have to **[hoist the scope](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)** and attach the event handler to an element that **will** exist on page load, such as `document`. You're looking for `$(document).on("change", ".one", function() {} )` instead of `$(".one").change(function() {} )`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Ajax Call... */
  $(document).on("change", ".one", function() {
    var one = $('.one').val();
    var company = $('.one').next();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'two.php',
      data: {
        'one': one
      },
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
        $(company).html(data);
      }
    });
  });

  /* To add more select boxes.. */
  var companyhtml = $(".one").html();
  $(".add").click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    $('<select class="one">' + companyhtml + '</select><select class="two"></select>').insertAfter($('.wrap'));
  });
});
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: "Hoist the scope"? This concept has nothing to do with event delegation, and the article you link to doesn't even mention events.

Comment: The title of the article is *literally* "JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting". I'm attempting to explain that `document` is available on page load, so you need to use the scope of `document` (rather than `.one`), and delegate the behaviour down to `.one`. Forgive my perhaps poor explanation, but you're free to add one of your own (instead of simply criticising mine).

Comment: The article is about scope within JS code, which has nothing at all to do with HTML structures or event delegation. Note that I agree that event delegation is the correct solution here, I'm just objecting to mentioning the completely unrelated concepts of scope and hoisting in connection with it. If you removed the words "hoist the scope and" from that sentence (along with the irrelevant link) I could vote for this answer.

Comment: it changes values for all select boxes... @ObsidianAge

Comment: You're using a class selector, so that's what I thought was the desired effect. You'll need to use ID selectors to target individual elements :)

Comment: use $(this), should fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".wrap").live('change','.one'function () {
        var one = $('.one').val();
        var company = $('.one').next();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'two.php',
            data: {'one': one},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $(company).html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$(".wrap").live('change','.one'function () {` => `$(".wrap").live('change','.one', function () {` and `live` is deprecated.

Comment: You've got the usage of `.live()` wrong, you've written it the way it should be for `.on()`. Except that the OP's code seems to be adding new elements *after* the `.wrap` element, not inside it.

Comment: you missed a comma, OP adding after .wrap is probably a bug @nnnnnn

Comment: @inarilo - It looks like a bug to me too, but that *is* what their code currently does so answers need to work with that unless they explicitly mention it.